# Installing eOS on Huawei Matebook 14 2020 Ryzen

Tags: ryzen

Anyone able to install eOS on Huawei Matebook 14 2020 Ryzen model, I am having a display and wireless issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by upgrading the kernel to 5.7.1-050701, Graphics issue fixed by just upgrading the kernel but had to install the Realtek driver manually for wireless to work. But right now all working fine.

Comment: where can i get the linux driver for the realtek device currently my matebook is offline i dont have an option to get it online with usb dongle etc.. kind regards milan

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest version of linux-firmware which contains it:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.178.3_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

reboot